# Resharper support for Silverlight Unit Test Application

Tags: silverlight, resharper

HI All

Is there a version of Reshaper that can be used to run Silverlight unit test. I am using Resharper 4.5 although it shows test icons against test methods in the class, but it does actually run the test.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of the AgUnit plugin.

Silverlight 3 support is currently working if you build the plugin from source, a new release is coming in the next couple of weeks.

If you want to run the tests on a build server, you should take a look at StatLight: http://statlight.codeplex.com/ You should be able to set it up easily with TeamCity.

*Update: Silverlight 3 support should be working in the new 0.2 release of AgUnit*.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it, although I am happy to be proven wrong. The test runner for MS Silverlight Unit Test suite is actually a Silverlight app, that runs in the browser. This is done in order to simulate the Silverlight runtime environment, which is different from desktop runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://agunit.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using Silverlight 3 and guess have to wait for next release of agunit.

do you know if this can be hooked with automated testing on build server. Are the any msbuild tasks to execute silverlight unit test. thanks.